# Accessing a directive from a controller in AngularJS: is there a proper solution?

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-directive

My scenario, as shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bLFF/2/): I have a directive which creates an empty iframe and attaches a load event which listens for clicks. On click calls `scope.emitClick()` in the controller, which then uses socket.io to send a message to the backend server. Even though I am not sure this is the best way to do it, it works.

As it happens, I need to receive notifications from the backend server: the controller uses socket.io to listen for messages, and upon receiving a certain message it should be able to change the contents of the iframe created in the directive.

Is there a way to call a method defined in the directive from the controller? Is there a proper way to do something similar to what I am trying to accomplish?

html:

```
<div ng-controller="SimulationController">
    <virtual-page id="testPage"/>
</div>
```

js:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.controller('SimulationController', function ($scope, socket) {    
    socket.on('update', function (data) {
        //do something to iframe contents
    });

    $scope.emitClick = function (page, target) {
        //socket.emit("click", { page: page, target: target });
        console.log("clicked");
    }
});

myModule.directive('virtualPage', function () {
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {       
        element.load(function () {
            console.log(attrs.id + ": contents loaded");

            jQuery(this).contents().off()
            .on("click", function (event) {
                console.log('>> clicked: ' + attrs.id + " - " + event.target);
                scope.emitClick(attrs.id, event.target);
                return false;
            })
        });

        element[0].contentWindow.contents = "<html><head></head><body>test...</body></html>";
        element[0].src = 'javascript:window["contents"]';
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>',
        replace: true,
        link : linkFn
    };
});

myModule.factory('socket', function () {
    return {
      on: function (eventName, callback) {
        //fake
      },
      emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
        //fake
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: if directive and controller will use same service, they will use one instance of that service (singleton).

Comment: so basically I should inject a service in both, but then how would the directive "listen" for instructions?

Comment: here is a video "directives talking to controller": http://www.egghead.io/video/LJmZaxuxlRc hope it will help. and "Directive communication" http://www.egghead.io/video/2CdivtU5ytY

Comment: thanks, but the problem is the other way around: the controller's job is to use sockets to communicate with the backend; I need to modify the DOM based on what the socket receives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying DOM in controller isn't an angular way IMHO. My approach to this kind problem would be:

In directive's linking function:

```
var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    ...
    scope.$watch('someData', function(newData) {
        // change element according to the new data
    });
};
```

In controller:

```
socket.on('update', function (data) {
    $scope.someData = newData; // Update data, so directive can take action against it
});
```

Comment: Indeed! `$watch` seems exactly what I needed! however, I also found a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/LWBsV/5/) that uses `$broadcast` and `$on`.. what would be best in my case?